# Debian [Wheezy] indigo install libconsole-bridge-dev -std=c++11 error

Tags: beaglebone, wheezy, c++11, beagleboneblack, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear reader,

While installing indigo on a fresh debian weezy install on the BeagleBone Black.
I came across an error.
In step 2.2.1 from [this](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Debian#Dependencies_not_available_in_the_Debian_Wheezy_branch) guide.

While doing the latest command for libconsole-bridge-dev: "sudo checkinstall make install"

I first change the name, as stated in the guide and then when pressing enter I get this.

> 

Installing with make install...

> 

========================= Installation results ===========================
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/console_bridge.dir/src/console.cpp.o
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/console_bridge.dir/src/console.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/console_bridge.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

> 

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

> 

Cleaning up...OK

> 

Bye.

Does anyone know what I should do first in order to overcome this error.

More info:

> gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14)

kernel version: 3.8.13-bone79

Thanks for the help

Kenavera

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223752/debian-%5Bwheezy%5D-indigo-install-libconsole-bridge-dev--std=c++11-error/) by [Kenavera](https://answers.ros.org/users/25226/kenavera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that my gcc version 4.6.3 has no support for C++ 11.
Therefore it wouldn't compile.

I updated it to gcc 4.7 with [this guide](http://lektiondestages.blogspot.nl/2013/05/installing-and-switching-gccg-versions.html) and that fixed my problems.

---

Originally posted by [Kenavera](https://answers.ros.org/users/25226/kenavera/) with karma: 56 on 2016-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0